# Custom Hash Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

Is it possible to create a custom hash algorithm, something that can provide an integer within a specific range. Example below.

(a,b) is the input to the hash. (a,b) != (b,a)
where a and b are both integers >= 0

The solution must be within the range (min,max).

Would this be possible? With this I would like (a,b) being hashed on two occasions to provide the same integer if also being given the same range as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course it would be possible.  Why don't you try writing one?

Comment: You could start from here: [hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and to get numbers between a specific range you can use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: It's impossible to guarantee that (a,b) != (b,a). Hashes aren't collision-proof.

Comment: @shmosel It's _absolutely_ possible to guarantee that, whenever `a != b`.  Consider the function  `(a,b) -> ( a > b ? 1 : 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

> (a,b) is the input to the hash. (a,b) != (b,a) where a and b are both
>   integers >= 0

No. Suppose a = b, then (a,b) = (b,a). This constraint violates consistency of hashing therefore impossible

Comment: That is a good point. What if we assumed that (a,b) cannot equal (b,a) except for in the case that they were equal? Or would assume that was the case in that one situation make it impossible as well?

Comment: @Jamie Then it is possible. But it will be hard to find a good one if (a, b) != (a, b) for all a, b. The easiest solution would be simply a - b. But this isn't a good one because it may not be uniformly distributed if a and b have some pattern. To address the min, max range issue is rather easy. Just transfrom your hash h into min + h % p, where p is some prime no greater than (max - min)